# Subclipse- update working copy

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, working-copy

I work on my school projects on two machines- my laptop and desktop.  Recently I've started using subclipse for version control, and have it plugged in Eclipse on both machines.

While working on a single machine, I understand the checkout/commit process and synchronizing in the Team Synchronizing tab.

So, how do I update the working copy of the other machine in subclipse without having to checkout and overwrite the entire project on the local machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the project and select

> Team->update

.

Comment: I had come across the Team>Update line, but had no idea how to find it.  Thanks!

Comment: So you know, Team>Synchronize is just a convenient user interface for combining Team>Update and then Team>Commit. So you can do it using Synchronize too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is Team > Upgrade

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, Subversion and CVS require you to have a server that hosts the repository. Then from any remote machine you checkout from and commit to this central repository. Wherever you host the main repository (you'll probably do it on your desktop?), you should checkout a copy on both your laptop and the desktop. Then you have: Working copy on your laptop, working copy on your desktop, and central repository on, e.g., your desktop.

This should solve your synchronization issues.

However: For your problem at hand, I strongly recommend looking into Git, another nice version control system that does not require a centralized host: All checkouts are treated equally, so you make changes on your laptop and push them to the desktop, or you make changes on your desktop and push them to the laptop, or you pull changes from the laptop to the desktop and vice versa.

Comment: I have my repository hosted by sliksvn.com.  Your solution would work if I had both systems on at the same time.  However, both are rarely on simultaneously, so there is the need for a centralized repository.

Comment: Oh, okay. You didn't specify where your repo was hosted so I assumed it was hosted locally. My bad.