# Update JBoss Developer SVN working copy using Subclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, svn, jboss, subclipse

I was following the remarks from this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205774/subclipse-update-working-copy) to "Update" my working copy with the lastest revision checked into our SVN repo.

This made perfect sense as it is the same way I would do it using TortoisSVN.  Click Update and you get most recent updated files.  However, there was a file I deleted from JBoss Developer (eclipse) and was expecting that using the Update option in JBDS would restore the most recent version of that file from the SVN

However, instead it just told me a conflict existed (file deleted from working copy, but exists on repository) and did not download it like it would with TortoisSVN.

So my question is - how do I get it to update where it actually redownloads the file I deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With TortoiseSVN, if you simply delete a file then it becomes "Missing".  If you delete a file in Eclipse, it tells Subclipse you deleted the file so it runs svn delete.  The equivalent of taking the Delete action in TortoiseSVN.  When you do an update, missing files are restored in your working copy, but deleted files are not -- because you said to delete it.

You are getting something else though.  In your case, there was a newer version of the file in the repository.  Because it is marked deleted locally, that is a tree conflict.  If you did the Delete action in TortoiseSVN you would see the same.

The tree conflict is so that you are aware that the file you deleted has been modified by someone.  So maybe you want to reconsider the delete etc.  The Team > Show Tree Conflicts option will show all tree conflicts and provide option to resolve it.

Comment: Ive tried using the Team > Show Tree Conflicts but nothing actually shows up.  But that was the same thought I had.  I think I may well just do a checkout of the same project which I assume will overwrite existing with all updated files.

Comment: Im going to accept this answer as I believe it is the solution, I think I just have some bug that is not allowing this to work for me.

Comment: At the point when you ran the Update option, which created this situation, it would be helpful if you looked at what Subclipse reported in the SVN Console view.